# Are biases narrowed towards the provenance of hard NP complete problems relevant?

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption, quantum-cryptography

I hear of randomized reduction, deterministic reduction and non-deterministic reduction of complexity from A to B problems. This could make things impossible for polynomial time adversary prying into NP - hard problems.

Are these biases in complexity what makes the computation infeasible if a problem cannot be solved in polynomial time?

Does it matter really, whether a problem' solution is bounded and affirmed in a deterministic turing machine or non-deterministic turing machine?

Is it not plausible that to achieve the right cryptosystem to serve us another 100 years a vital consideration must be giving to a mix of all these reduction in polynomial time within a scope or formation of naturally existing context. e.g lattice or their matrix images?

**FYI**
Please think about quantum resistant possibilities as you answer these questions. A good crypto scheme will give rise to a data stream that will bear no information but a verifier could still validate a prover without knowing much of the secret there in.

[AJI04] Miklos Ajtai. Generating hard instances of lattice problems. Quaderni di Matematica, 13:1–32,2004. Preliminary version in STOC 1996. – Jossy J. Umezurike 2 mins ago

[AKS] M. Ajtai, R. Kumar, and D. Sivakumar,A Sieve Algorithm for the Shortest Vector Problem, Proc.33rd Symp. Theory of Computing (STOC), pp. 601–610, 2001 
https://github.com/jumezurike/backend-master-lokdonSKI/blob/master/README.md
https://www.cs.uml.edu/~wang/acc-forum/avg/avgnp/node29.html

http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~sacook/homepage/1971.pdf

Comment: [AJI04] Miklos Ajtai. Generating hard instances of lattice problems. Quaderni di Matematica, 13:1–32,2004. Preliminary version in STOC 1996.

Comment: [AKS] M. Ajtai, R. Kumar, and D. Sivakumar,A Sieve Algorithm for the Shortest Vector Problem, Proc.33rd Symp. Theory of Computing (STOC), pp. 601–610, 2001   https://www.cs.uml.edu/~wang/acc-forum/avg/avgnp/node29.html

Comment: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~sacook/homepage/1971.pdf

Comment: I strongly believe that it depends on how you look at it. These are tautology.

Comment: 3. Since P is usually an element of NP. We are not certain of NP being in P. unless some problem X can be reduced to NP: There is a fitting problem of NP hard caliber that could be reduced to NP complete problem.

Comment: hey man, do you really understand what are you talking about? )))

Comment: I am sure I do sir.